# HDMI sound not working

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, hdmi

Hello I have problem with hdmi connected sound, but nothing I can found worked for me I have lenovo legion y530 15 inch with hdmi on nvidia gtx 1060 GPU on Ubuntu 20.04 I tried killing pulse daemon rebooting I have latest proprietary tested driver but hdmi is not visible in sound settings and in pulseaudio is "unavailable" next to every HDMI output. Please someone help I'm really mad of that.

Comment: What do you mean by "HDMI sound"?  You have a display right?  HDMI can carry high fidelity sound, *but only if it's accompanied by video*

Comment: I connected via hdmi cable to television and I wanted to use its speakers instead of laptop build in speakers.

Comment: You need to set the TV as a display

Comment: Have you ever found the solution? I have the same issue.